# Laravel and angular: failed to load module script

Tags: javascript, php, angular, laravel

So to begin with I am getting this error on my server (on my local machine it's working fine):

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

I am trying to host laravel and angular with on the same server/app. And I do not know what's going wrong.

This is what I have in my `index.html` and my `angular.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Vakmanbv</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a04d011c3a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>:root{--accent-color:#68C5D4;--black:#000000;--white:#FFFFFF;--text-color:#151515;--header-color:#151515;--header-text:#EEEEEE;--darkest-card:#333333;--darker-card:#666666;--dark-card:#999999;--card:#CCCCCC;--white-background:#EEEEEE;--blue-background:#3D5F92;--salmon-background:#FFA18C;--cream-background:#F2EBD5;--green-background:#72A187;--brown-background:#B49A85;--corporate-blue:#144C8C;--corporate-lightblue:#8AB9EE;--corporate-darkblue:#1F3C58;--corporate-gray:#627D9F;--corporate-cream:#D3CEBE;--corporate-darkgray:#1C242C;--error-red:#FF5851;--warning-yellow:#F3C130;--success-green:#43CD80;--whatsapp:#25D366;--whatsapp-dark:#075E54}body{margin:0}body{font-family:Segoe UI,Tahoma,Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif;color:var(--text-color)}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/angular/styles.e7c4bfb78927fe9b.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/angular/styles.e7c4bfb78927fe9b.css"></noscript></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="/assets/angular/runtime.134360f5ea2776bf.js" type="module"></script><script src="/assets/angular/polyfills.d1423aacda52be91.js" type="module"></script><script src="/assets/angular/main.52925ad117c1838a.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>
```

I've tried changing this:

```
<base href="/">
```

To the following things:

```
<base href=".">
```

```
<base href="domain.com/assets/angular">
```

But both did not work.

In my `angular.json` in the configurations I have this:

```
"production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputPath": "../../../public/assets/angular",
              "deployUrl": "/assets/angular/",
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
```

And this is how I build it:

```
"build:prod": "ng build --prod && cp ../../../public/assets/angular/index.html ../../views/angular.blade.php",
```

The server I am on won't let me install node so I cant build it on the server, I have to manually put the files on the server.

Thanks for helping!